# Resolve-DnsName resolves hostname of IP, but nslookup fails

Tags: reverse-dns, nslookup, resolve, dns-lookup

There are some IP address that `nslookup` can't resolve (both on Windows and Linux).

### Problem:

I can find the IP of the hostname, but reverse lookup fails.

```
PS C:\> nslookup.exe somehost2
Server:  corpdns.mydomain.com
Address:  10.248.2.1

Name:    somehost2.corp.mydomain.com
Address:  10.185.140.22

# Reverse lookup of the same IP fails:

PS C:\> nslookup.exe 10.185.140.22
Server:  corpdns.mydomain.com
Address:  10.248.2.1

*** corpdns.mydomain.com can't find 10.185.140.22: Non-existent domain
```

However,`Resolve-DnsName` PowerShell command return the hostname for the reverse lookup.

```
PS C:\> Resolve-DnsName 10.185.140.22

Name                           Type   TTL   Section    NameHost
----                           ----   ---   -------    --------
22.140.185.10.in-addr.arpa.    PTR    1200  Question   somehost2
```

There are two unusual things I observe here:

1. It comes from the **Question** section
2. It returns the hostname without the DNS domain.

With other IP addresses (that `nslookup` can resolve), we see it comes from the **Answer** section and with a DNS domain.

```
PS C:\> Resolve-DnsName 10.210.0.127

Name                           Type   TTL   Section    NameHost
----                           ----   ---   -------    --------
127.0.210.10.in-addr.arpa      PTR    1200  Answer     somehost1.corp.mydomain.com
```

By the way, `ping` with the `/a` flag also succeeds resolving the name on Windows:

```
PS C:\> ping /a 10.185.140.22

Pinging somehost2 [10.185.140.22] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.185.140.22: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=127
Reply from 10.185.140.22: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=127
```

But I cannot find an equivalent flag for `ping` in Linux.

### My question:

What are `Resolve-DnsName` and `ping` doing differently than `nslookup`?

My main problem is when I try to resolve the IP in Linux. I've tried several `nslookup` and `dig` command to no avail. Is there an equivalent to `Resolve-DnsName` in Linux?

### Clarification:

Most of the IP addresses can be resolved by `nslookup` as well, the problem is only with a specific subset of hosts in our environment.

### Update: `nslookup` in debug mode

```
PS C:\> nslookup.exe -d 10.185.140.22
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        1.2.248.10.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  1.2.248.10.in-addr.arpa
        name = corpdns.mydomain.com
        ttl = 1200 (20 mins)

------------
Server:  corpdns.mydomain.com
Address:  10.248.2.1

------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        22.140.185.10.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  185.10.in-addr.arpa
        ttl = 900 (15 mins)
        primary name server = gdns602.corp.mydomain.com
        responsible mail addr = hostmaster.mydomain.com
        serial  = 35869652
        refresh = 300 (5 mins)
        retry   = 900 (15 mins)
        expire  = 604800 (7 days)
        default TTL = 900 (15 mins)

------------
*** corpdns.mydomain.com can't find 10.185.140.22: Non-existent domain
```

### Update #2

`Resolve-DnsName` fails for those systems when using different flags such as: `-DnsOnly`, `-NoHostsFile`, `-LlmnrNetbiosOnly` (but does work for the other IP address that `nslookup` can resolve).

```
PS C:\> Resolve-DnsName 10.185.140.22 -DnsOnly
Resolve-DnsName : 22.140.185.10.in-addr.arpa : DNS name does not exist
At line:1 char:1
+ Resolve-DnsName 10.185.140.22 -DnsOnly
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (22.140.185.10.in-addr.arpa:String) [Resolve-DnsName], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DNS_ERROR_RCODE_NAME_ERROR,Microsoft.DnsClient.Commands.ResolveDnsName



PS C:\> Resolve-DnsName 10.185.140.22 -NoHostsFile
Resolve-DnsName : 22.140.185.10.in-addr.arpa : DNS name does not exist
At line:1 char:1
+ Resolve-DnsName 10.185.140.22 -NoHostsFile
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (22.140.185.10.in-addr.arpa:String) [Resolve-DnsName], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DNS_ERROR_RCODE_NAME_ERROR,Microsoft.DnsClient.Commands.ResolveDnsName



PS C:\> Resolve-DnsName 10.185.140.22 -LlmnrNetbiosOnly
Resolve-DnsName : 22.140.185.10.in-addr.arpa : DNS record does not exist
At line:1 char:1
+ Resolve-DnsName 10.185.140.22 -LlmnrNetbiosOnly
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (22.140.185.10.in-addr.arpa:String) [Resolve-DnsName], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RECORD_DOES_NOT_EXIST,Microsoft.DnsClient.Commands.ResolveDnsName
```

Comment: Can you show the results of `nslookup -d 10.185.140.22` on Windows, or the `dig` output, or a packet capture of the received DNS response?

Comment: @user1686 I've updated my question with the debug information as requested, thanks.

Comment: Do you get any different results from `Resolve-DnsName -DnsOnly -NoHosts` (and from `-LlmnrNetbiosOnly`, etc)?

Comment: @user1686 updated my question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After examining `wireshark`, I saw that indeed those IPs weren't available in DNS:

```
Standard query response 0xb20a No such name PTR 22.140.185.10.in-addr.arpa
```

But the answer came from `NBSTAT` query in `NBNS` (NetBIOS Name Service) protocol.

The reason is that those hosts don't have static IP - they get their dynamic IP through DHCP, so they weren't registered in the DNS Name Servers.

I was able to get the expect answer in Linux using the `nmblookup` command:

```
$ nmblookup -A 10.185.140.22
Looking up status of 10.185.140.22
        SOMEHOST2       <00> -         M <ACTIVE> 
        XXX             <00> - <GROUP> M <ACTIVE> 
        SOMEHOST2       <20> -         M <ACTIVE>
```

Comment: `they get their dynamic IP through DHCP, so they weren't registered in the DNS Name Servers.` Static address assignment is not linked to the presence or absence of a DNS record.  There's hundreds of millions of endpoints that register DNS records and get an IP address from DHCP.  Also, if the problem is "nslookup isn't resolving a name", the solution is to create a DNS record.

Comment: @GregAskew Those are employees laptops that are not connected all the time. Their IP addresses might change every time they connect to the network. The DNS servers can resolve the hostnames, but cannot reverse resolve their IP address. I'm not familiar enough with DNS, so I don't know why DNS can resolve only the IPs of the hostnames but not the other way around. I don't know if it's a good question to open in this site, but if you can explain it it would be nice.

Comment: Internally, a reverse DNS record has almost no value. If you want to create one, fine. In nearly all cases it doesn't do anything, unless you want to create something fragile that could break unexpectedly. So it isn't something that is causing a problem that would have a solution, or information that would be generally useful.  I would argue that in large environments where there could be a lot of churn, a reverse lookup zone may actually have negative value, due to replicating those records that aren't used, and creating unnecessary chatter.

Comment: @GregAskew the value of reverse DNS lookup is mostly helpful for debugging and troubleshooting. For instance, let's say your apache logs show excessive queries from a certain IP, and you want to know where it came from. In a case where the hostnames are meaningful (for instance, the employee laptops contain the usernames in their hostnames), it will help you know who to contact.